# How can a deterministic or non-deterministic automaton accept the language of square strings?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, nondeterminism

I don't know how to prove or show the following fact.

$\quad$ $\{xx|x \in \Sigma^\ast\} $ can be accepted by a queue automaton.

If it would be possible, show by deterministic queue automaton. If not, by non-deterministic queue automaton.

If it's not that hard and if I can, please give me a hint.

Comment: We generally prefer that you ask only one question per post.  We also prefer that you show us what progress you've made.  Perhaps it is worth spending a little more time on $L_1$: can you at least find a nondeterministic queue automaton?

Comment: @D.W. Sorry, you're right. I changed the question. Actually no, could you please give me some explanation/hint? then I try and come back

Answer (score 1):

Working with a queue automaton for me is intuitively equivalent to working with a circular tape.

Read the input $w$ from the automaton, and put it on the tape. Add two markers $A$ and $B$, so we obtain $Aw_1Bw_2$. Now we can one by one eat a letter after $A$ and one after $B$.

For the deterministic variant it suffices to put $B$ exactly in the middle of the input string. That position can be found using a method similar to this: [How to find middle element of linked list in one pass?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/56221/4287)